# How do I enrich DependencyTelemetry?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.0 application with ApplicationInsights enabled via Serilog using the following in Startup.cs

```cs
        TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new DependencyInitializer(ServiceProvider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>()));

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
            .CreateLogger();
```

DependencyINitializer looks like this:

```cs
  public class DependencyInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

        public DependencyInitializer(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
        {
            _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
        }

        public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
        {
            if (telemetry is DependencyTelemetry)
            {
                telemetry.Context.Properties.Add("RequestId", _contextAccessor.HttpContext.TraceIdentifier);
            }
        }
    }
```

Using the debugger I've found `ITelemetryInitializer` only intercepts `TraceTelemetry` and `ExceptionTelemetry`. However, `DependencyTelemetry` is getting written to application insigghts. I really need to enhance the `customDimensions` field because right now it looks like this:

> {"_MS.ProcessedByMetricExtractors":"(Name:'Dependencies', Ver:'1.0')","AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Production","DeveloperMode":"true"}

How can I intercept DependencyTelemetry objects before they get sent to app insights so I may add customDimensions to them?

I can intercept requests with middleware like this:

```cs
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseCorrelationProperties(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        return app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {

                var requestTelemetry = context.Features.Get<RequestTelemetry>();
                if (requestTelemetry != null)
                {
                    requestTelemetry.Context.Properties["CorrelationId"] = correlationId;
                }

                await next.Invoke();
            });
    }
```

And those properties get added, so I know Serilog is using the "normal" Application insights mechanisms.

Comment: Afaik serilog only support exceptions, events and traces so it won't send dependency telemetry to AI ([source](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-applicationinsights/blob/master/src/Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights/ExtensionMethods/LogEventExtensions.cs)) The dependency telemetry probably comes from another source, not from serilog.

Comment: @PeterBons Well, serilog doesn't send dependency events itself. However, as I proved in my edits, its just setting up Appinsights "normally" and piping events, traces and exeptions to it from the log calls it receives.

Comment: any updates on this thread? I am using .Net Core 3.1